# Local .js files not being uploaded upon GCP deploy

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I followed [this basic tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr#deploying_the_functions) which deploys three functions. So currently I have successfully deployed three Cloud Functions.

I wrote a fourth function in my index.js file:

```
const userInput = require('user-input.js');

// more code in the middle from the tutorial

exports.compareUserToDetectedText = async (event) => {
  input = userInput.getUserInput(`${originalFilename}.txt`);
  console.log(input);
}
```

and created a new file, user-input.js in the same directory as my index.js file:

```
// Get a reference to the Cloud Storage component
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

exports.getUserInput = (filename) => {
  const bucket = storage.bucket('my_bucket_name');
  const remoteFile = bucket.file(filename);

 }
```

When I try to deploy this function:

```
gcloud functions deploy ocr-compare \
--runtime nodejs10 \
--trigger-bucket [my trigger bucket] \
--entry-point compareUserToDetectedText \
--set-env-vars "^:^GCP_PROJECT=[project ID],RESULT_BUCKET=[my result bucket]"
```

I find this error in my logs:

```
"Function 'compareUserToDetectedText' is not defined in the provided module." 
Did you specify the correct target function to execute?
Could not load the function, shutting down.
```

When I [deploy the functions in the tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr#deploying_the_functions), the source code updates for that function. Why is the source code not being uploaded for this new compareUserToDetectedText function?

Comment: Can you provide the whole index.js  files? it seems 'compareUserToDetectedText' is not set properly.

Comment: as you include the user-input.js, I beleive you should deploy getUserInput first, try to deploy getUserInput then deploy compareUserToDetectedText.